# pidof giving inaccurate result

Tags: linux, php, command-line-interface

I want to get the pid of a php script:

```
php /var/www/html/test.php
```

I have a couple of other php scripts running as well, for instance

```
php /var/www/html/hello.php
php /var/www/html/world.php
```

When I run `pidof -s -x php /var/www/html/test.php`, it randomly gives me the pid of any of the 3 running scripts. I think it's because it's only seeing the php after -x and ignoring the rest. I tried it with quotes and I didn't get any result at all.

```
pidof -s -x 'php /var/www/html/test.php'
```

Comment: What you are actually asking pidof to do is to give you a single result (-s), also checking for scripts (-x), of either "php" or "/var/www/html/test.php".  I suspect you are assuming pidof will AND the results, which it doesn't.  Removing "php" from the command line is probably more what you want.

Comment: I tried that and that didn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
pgrep -f 'php /var/www/html/test.php'
```